# Are scripts added dynamically with appendChild() executed sequentially or in parallel?

Tags: javascript

I'm adding scripts to a page dynamically using code similar to this:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = 'script.js';
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

The first script I add is jQuery bundled with a few plugins after that (all in one JS file), then the second script uses jQuery and some of the other objects created in the first JS file added.

The problem is that errors are being thrown in the second script saying jQuery, along with several other things are undefined.

I assumed scripts added to the DOM in this manner would be parsed/executed sequentially, but these errors would indicate they are executed in parallel.

Which is it?

Comment: They are executed async. So they are loaded in parallel which means errors occur unexpected -> sometimes there is an error sometimes not (depends on which lib loaded faster). Btw. not sure what you are trying but i would recommend you to have a look at require.js ;)

Comment: @FabianLurz that's what I was afraid of. I was hoping that wasn't the case, though, because when script tags are in HTML when the page is loaded they are loaded synchronously, right?

Comment: Correct! If you want to load them in parallel but still lib dependent you really need something like requirejs. With a lib like that you can use a shim config -> basically this configuration sets dependencies for each script/lib you want to include and ensures it is loaded in correct order ;) Little sample: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you'll be advised to use a library to handle this, but I'm not a big fan of libraries since they often times offer a lot more than you need, which is not necessarily a bad thing though.

To load scripts in order you need to bind the second to load when the first one has finished loading.

```
var script1 = document.createElement('script');
script1.onload = function() {
    // script 1 has loaded
    var script2 = document.createElement('script');
    document.head.appendChild(script2);
    script2.src = "...";
}

document.head.appendChild(script1);
script1.src = "...";
```